# default language root level

Tags: .htaccess, seo, redirect

Hi 
I currently run a multilingual website organized as follow:
    site.com/fr/ (france),
    site.com/be/ (belgium),
    site.com/uk/ (UK)
    ...
    and site.com is a page where we can select countries/ languages.

I heard and read that it's not a good practice to do so, that I should rather set a default language for site.com

my question are:
1- should i add for example US english as default language?
2- remove the /fr/ and set a permanent redirect to the root (.com/fr/product redirected to .com/product)
3- or maybe do you have better suggestions?

Thanks you so much in advance

Comment: I worked on a project at school that dynamically modified that language of Moodle. Moodle had a different language pack for each language. I know that this doesn't directly answer your question, but this may give you some ideas: https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Multi_language_content

Comment: Thanks Daryl, i'll have a look at your link..

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing with one of my sites. But, in PHP, I change the position of the root (with or without /fr/ links). That way I can use a default language: site.com/

I choose this language automatically, with user browser language preferences. For the first page, and after link to the correct language (or to others with links). For me, it's the best SEO solution.

I just have to add `rel="canonical"` link elements, to avoid the duplicate or similar content:
[Google: Use canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Croises for your reply, that's exactely what i wanna do, but my questions are:
- is it worth doing it in term of SEO?
- should i move all the .com/fr/ content to .com/ using a 301 redirection knowing that france is my main target...

Comment: I don't think so. I test in `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`, and use the first language as defaut. Like that it's the best for each language. And for SEO nothing change. But all the "good" links are for the home page whatever language. But if a language is much more important to you than others, make a redirection can be better.

Comment: Well, the first thing to tell you is that i don't manage my site by language, but by country (site.com/be/, site.com/fr/, site.com/uk/, ...) and i read everywhere in the web that it's not a good practice to redirect based on $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] !!<br>
so i remain still confused about what i should be doing!!

Comment: In your cases country is often part of the language code. SEO is one thing, comfort of use another.

Comment: Hi, i'm gonna ask my question differently :)
Is is a good idea to move all the content of site.com/fr/ to site.com using the redirection rule: `RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` ??

Comment: I do not think so, but that's just my opinion. 
I like to see the divisions, and facilitate access.